# simple if loop not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, if-statement

My code looks like this

```
   <html>
   <form method="post">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th colspan='3' style="text-align:center;">Enter Subject wise weightage
          </th>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input type='hidden' name='Subject[]' value='ANATOMY' />ANATOMY
            </td>
            <td><input type='number' class='form-control individual' name='q_num[]' max=8 sub='ANATOMY'placeholder='Enter the number of Questions'/>     <p class='text-danger ANATOMY_error'></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td colspan='2'><input type='hidden' name='Subject[]' value='BIOCHEMISTRY' />BIOCHEMISTRY
             </td>
             <td><input type='number' class='form-control individual' name='q_num[]' max=4 sub='BIOCHEMISTRY'placeholder='Enter the number of Questions'/><p class='text-danger BIOCHEMISTRY_error'></p>
             </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input type='hidden' name='Subject[]' value='PHYSIOLOGY' />PHYSIOLOGY
            </td>
            <td><input type='number' class='form-control individual' name='q_num[]' max=3 sub='PHYSIOLOGY'placeholder='Enter the number of Questions'/><p class='text-danger PHYSIOLOGY_error'></p>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input type='hidden' name='Subject[]' value='ORTHOPEDICS' />ORTHOPEDICS
            </td>
             <td><input type='number' class='form-control individual' name='q_num[]' max=2 sub='ORTHOPEDICS'placeholder='Enter the number of Questions'/><p class='text-danger ORTHOPEDICS_error'></p>
            </td>
            </tr>   
        </table>    
       </form>
```

And my jquery is like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('.individual').blur(function(){
   var m =$(this).attr("max");
   var e = $(this).val();
   var s= $(this).attr("sub");
   var error = "."+ s +"_error";

   if(e > m){

   $(error).text("Please enter low value");
   }else{

        $(error).text('');
    }

    });

  });
```

This worked for me before but now I am unable to make it work. The `blur` function fires and works fine until the `if` loop is started.

Comment: Please define "not working". Notice, that `.attr()` and `.val()` return strings, and comparing strings might give you unexpected results.

Comment: Works like a charm :http://jsfiddle.net/af6nxeeo/1/

Comment: Excellent .Very thank you. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble here is that your value are strings, and you are comparing them as if they were integers.  SO, when you do the comparison, you need to convert them on the way:

```
if(parseInt(e) > parseInt(m)){
//and so on 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working after I modified the code as below!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $('.individual').blur(function(){
        var m =parseInt($(this).attr("max"));
        var e = parseInt($(this).val());
        var s= $(this).attr("sub");
        var error = "."+ s +"_error";
     if(e>m){

             $(error).text("Please enter low value");
           }else{

            $(error).text('');
       }
     });

  });
```

Thank you..